# express: add handler to route with any method

Tags: rest, express, routes, same-origin-policy

I want to add a header to any endpoint, no matter what method is used (get, post, put, delete)

For get I do it like this:

```
app.get('/*', function(req,res,next){
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next(); // http://expressjs.com/guide.html#passing-route control
});
```

I wonder if there's a better way to do it that doesn't involve copying for app.post, app.put and app.delete

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for app.all()

Your example would then become:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
});
```

See docs at

- http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html#route-methods
- http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.all